# How to sort files by multicolumn

Tags: bash, sort, file-sorting

My file has 3 columns and I want to sort the data in the file by column 1 (DESC), column 2(ASC) and save the result to another file. How can I do that?

Comment: ... sort with what? Bash? MySQL? Python? Perl?

Comment: @Rinzwind you're seducing him to ask a programming question, which it would be the moment he mentions a language  :)

Comment: @Rinzwind, Bash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sort` has the option to sort by multiple columns, do:

```
sort -k1,1 -k2,2 file.txt
```

The above will `sort` the file first by whitespace separated column 1, then by column 2.

You can also set other delimiter than any whitespace by the `-t` option, e.g. setting `,` as the delimiter:

```
sort -t ',' -k1,1 -k2,2 file.txt
```

Check `man sort`.